# import multiple table data into mysql using single csv file

Tags: mysql, file-upload, csv, multiple-tables

I have this table in csv file

[image]

Now i have two mysql tables dealing with this csv file,

Data A, B, C has to get stored in `Table1` whereas data D, E, F, G, H has to get stored in `Table2`.

I have the above formatted csv file, how can i upload its data to `MYSQL` database??

So that from same file input can be done for different tables.

Comment: Copy paste into Google docs and do this: http://blog.pamelafox.org/2009/05/how-to-convert-google-spreadsheet-into.html :)

Comment: If you are looking at doing it with the `LOAD DATA INFILE` SQL command, you can have a look at this article:
https://blog.terresquall.com/2022/05/splitting-csv-file-into-multiple-mysql-tables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it's working well, you can add as many values as possible depending on the number of columns you have in the CSV file.

```
  <?php   

 $fname = $_FILES['csv_file']['name'];     
  $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);             

        $filename = $_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_      name'];   
 $handle = fopen($filename, "r");      
 if(!$handle){
 die ('Cannot open file for reading');
  }      
              while (($data = fgetcsv($handle,      10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
 {
          $query = "INSERT INTO tablename        (col1_csv, col2_csv)
 values ('$data[0]', '$data[1]');
   mysql_query($query) 
   or die(mysql_error());


        $query1 = "INSERT INTO tablename        (col1_csv, col2_csv)
    values ('$data[0]', '$data[1]');
   mysql_query($query1) 
 or die(mysql_error());
 }
 fclose($handle);
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably only via custom script (PHP or so)...

But it's usually not hard to split CSV into 2 files and import both into separate tables using **[LOAD_DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)** function from MySQL directly. It will be MUCH faster than using phpMyAdmin or similar scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Load the data in a `temporary table`, then split up in `two tables`.

Then `drop` that `temporary table`. I somewhere read that php can do this, but I cannot help in php codes.